# How to Loop with the final result formatted differently?

Tags: loop

I need to list post_title's in this specific format (note the last title in the list **must not** have a comma)

```
    "post_title","post_title","post_title"
```

I thought a mini-loop might work. Here's what I'm using

```
            <?php query_posts('cat=0$posts_per_page=-1'); // query to show all posts independant from what is in the center;
                if (have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        '<?php the_title(); ?>',
                    <?php endwhile; endif;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>]">
```

But I need the final post_title to have no trailing comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the context for this, but `query_posts` probably isn't what you want to use. (See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)).

(*Untested*). I would use get_posts:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts'=>-1,
  'category'=>0
 ));
```

And then use [`wp_list_pluck`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/functions.php#L3277) to get the titles:

```
$post_titles = wp_list_pluck($posts,'post_title');
$post_titles = array_map('esc_html',$post_titles);
```

Finally, the php `implode` function an list them with commas:

```
echo '"'.implode('","',$post_titles).'"';
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's "TypeAhead" javascript plugin [link] http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

And the formatting is this

`<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]>`

Comment: So I'm replacing the data-source of city names with data-source of post titles.

Comment: Use the above to echo the titles in the data-source attribute :)

Comment: Almost works Stephen. But the data-source values need to be enclosed in quotes `"the_title","the_title","the_title"`

Comment: This worked Stephen. Thanks.

***However*** it only ever returns 5 post titles? Where the query_post version (shown below) pulls all post titles (they both use `cat=0$posts_per_page=-1`). 

`data-source='[<?php query_posts('cat=0$posts_per_page=-1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>"<?php if( ($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count) ){echo(",");} else {echo '';} ;?><?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>]'`

I still need to work out how to link the drop-downs to the post permalink, but that's another question entirely.

Comment: oops... Updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

change that line:

```
'<?php the_title(); ?>',
```

to:

```
<?php if( $wp_query->current_post ) { echo ', ';} ?>'<?php the_title(); ?>'
```

Comment: I went with @StephenHarris's method. Thanks anyway Michael.